# Добавление элементов в Map() Java

Tags: java

```
TreeMap<Integer, List<String>> reverseMap = new TreeMap<Integer, List<String>>();

        for(Map.Entry<String, Integer> e: fMap.entrySet()) {
            if(reverseMap.containsKey(e.getValue())) {
                List<String> l = reverseMap.get(e.getValue());
                l.add(e.getKey());
                reverseMap.put(e.getValue(), l);
            } else {
                List<String> l = new ArrayList<String>();
                l.add(e.getKey());
                reverseMap.put(e.getValue(), l);
            }

        }

        for(Map.Entry<Integer, List<String>> e: reverseMap.entrySet()) {
            System.out.println(e.getKey() + ": " + e.getValue());
        }
```

почему если убрать **reverseMap.put(e.getValue(), l);** из if, но оставить в else, в выводе все равно будут все пары ключей/значений? То есть **if** добавляет только массивы из нескольких стрингов, а **else** - из одного, но почему если убрать put из **if**, все массивы все равно будут правильно вписаны?

Answer (score 1):

Ну видимо, потому что

```
List<String> l = reverseMap.get(e.getValue());
```

вернет ссылку уже на существующий список, соответственно с ним и работать будет (List ведь мутабельный тип) (а этот список уже у  вас занесен в мапу)

По сути строка

```
reverseMap.put(e.getValue(), l);
```

в if и не нужна (там происходит примерно такое, мапа видит что у нее есть значение с этим ключом и вместо списка[этого же] заносит опять этот список)

Надеюсь Вы поняли :)